# Product of Ideals Explaination

Tags: number-theory

Could anyone explain the logic in these steps please I don't understand any of it really. How do the two terms become four and the simplification confuses me also.
(5, −1 + √21)(5, −1 − √21) = (25, −5 − 5√21, −5 + 5√21, [−1 + √21][−1 − √21]) 
 = (5)

Comment: The product of two finitely generated ideals $I,J$ is the ideal which is generated by the products of the generators of $I$ and $J$ by definition.

Comment: @mathmax Not by definition but, rather, by a simple consequence of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing $(5,-1+21^{1/2})=A.5+A.(-1+21^{1/2})$ ($A$ is the ring you are working on). And multiply both terms as you are used to with numbers (You are actually doing this for every $a\in A$) and remember that adding elements of the ideal to the generators, doesn't change the ideal. For example $-5+5.21^{1/2} + -5-5.21^{1/2}=-10$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the product $IJ$ of two ideals is the smallest ideal containing their elementwise products, which is the ideal generated by the elementwse products. In particular

$\,IJ = (a,b)(c,d) = (ac,ad,bc,bd) = K.\,$ Let's prove it. If $\,ar+bs\in (a,b),\ ct+du\in (c,d)\,$ then their product $= ac(rs)+ad(ru)+bc(st)+bd(su)\in (acc,ad,bc,bd)$ so $\,IJ\subseteq K.\,$ Conversely each element of $\,K\,$ is in the product $IJ$ by definition, e.g. $\,a\in I,\ c\in J\,\Rightarrow\,ac\in IJ.\,$ Therefore $\,K\subseteq IJ,\,$ hence $\, K = IJ.$

If we write $\,A=(a),\, B=(b)\dots$ then the above is $\ (A\!+\!B)(C\!+\!D) = AC\!+\!AD\!+\!BC\!+\!BD\,$ which follows by a few applications of the *Ideal Distributive Law* $\ I(J\!+\!K) = IJ\! +\! IK.$